# Coverity complains about uncaught exception(s). What security issue are linked to such?

Tags: c++, security, coverity

I'm writing C++ code for Linux. I have all resources wrapped in RAII objects.

If my software throws and there is no try/catch block anywhere. What could happen?

I'm mainly asking in terms of security because that's what I'm interested in. If resources get lost, it is bad too, especially if such could also cause security issues.

I'm being very broad on purpose and do not want to give a specific example of the code that generates such a Coverity issue, because if there is even one single case where this is bad practice, I'll have to fix my code.

Comment: If you don't catch an exception then the program terminates. If this can be triggered remotely it's a denial of service attack.

Comment: If your code is throwing than there's an error somewhere that **can** potentially cause a security issue. But this question is way too general to really answer as every error isn't a security risk but every security risk is caused by some programming error.

Comment: In this very case, it would be a try/catch in the main() function, and it would anyway terminate. So I personally do not see the point... and thus I'm not too sure I understand why Coverity would complain about it.

Comment: A try/catch block in `main` will, for example, allow your application to "continue" in a meaningful way, or print a meaningful error message rather than the runtime's "terminated due to uncaught exception" (or whatever it prints). Coverity is not all about security, it is about "programming correctly" - handling errors and not doing generally bad stuff (that can later on lead to other problems). If the code can throw, then you should, somewhere centrally at the very least, catch it, and not let it fall off the edge of your program.

Comment: As Mats says, Coverity isn't just about security. If your program crashes and dies, simply because you failed to catch a "can't open file" exception or something, and a user was trying to do something with the program, that's also bad. Maybe the user isn't harmed by a theft of personal data or something, but they're not going to be very happy, either.